# Finding the outward normal to a straight line in 2D

Tags: vectors, python

Suppose you have a straight line from $\underline{a}=(2,0)$ to $\underline{b}=(1,4)$.

If we consider the vector format of this straight line, then it will be: $\underline{b}-\underline{a}$. That is the vector: $(1,4)-(2,0)=(-1,4)$.

And I know that, the two vectors: $(4,1)$ and $(-4,-1)$ will be the normal vectors to this straight line $\underline{b}-\underline{a}$.

My question is, whether there is a way to identify the outward normal. That is if we travel from $\underline{a}$ to $\underline{b}$, then the one on your right hand side.

Appreciate your help

(I'm using Python programming. So I included that as well in the name tags)

Comment: I think the question, as it is, probably makes no much senseÑwhere do you intent to "anchor" your normal vector, meaning: what it is its inital point?  Now, knowing the general poisition of $\;\underline b-\underline a\;$ (in the first quadrant pointing towards the second quadrant), it is easy to see that the normal vector you want must be $\;\binom 41\;$, in the general rightwards direction...

Comment: Is your definition of "outward" based on (a) pointing to the side away from the origin, or (b) on the righthand side as we move from start to finish?  They happen to coincide in this example, but which one do you want generally?

Comment: @BrianTung It is the second one... (right hand side as we move from start to finish)

Answer (score 2):

You want the outward normal to point away from the origin. Choose any point on the line. You can choose $\underline{a}$. Then the origin is in the direction $\underline 0-\underline a$. Then look at the angle between the normal and this vector. In fact, you can simplify and just look at the sign of the dot product. Say your normal is $(n_x,n_y)$. Then
$$(n_x,n_y)\cdot(-b_x,-by)=-n_xb_x-n_yb_y$$
If the dot product is negative, your normal points away from the origin. If it's positive, the normal is towards origin. If it's $0$, then the original line goes through the origin, so there are no outward or inward directions.

Answer (score 2):

Just rotate the vector $\vec b-\vec a$ clockwise by 90° or $\vec a-\vec b$ counterclockwise by 90° using the rotation matrix.